# RavenDB build 35215 Concurrent merge failed warning

Tags: ravendb

That warning is spamming the logs, it happens every few seconds. can someone tells me what does it mean, how is it affecting the raven server and how to fix it ?

Message

> Concurrent merge failed

Exception

> Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException: Exception of type
>   'Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException' was thrown. --->
>   Lucene.Net.Index.CorruptIndexException: docs out of order (0 <= 0 )
>   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.HandleMergeException(Exception t,
>   OneMerge merge)    at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Merge(OneMerge
>   merge)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.MergeThread.Run()    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.HandleMergeException(Exception
>   exc)    at
>   Raven.Database.Indexing.ErrorLoggingConcurrentMergeScheduler.HandleMergeException(Exception
>   exc) in
>   C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-3.5\Raven.Database\Indexing\ErrorLoggingConcurrentMergeScheduler.cs:line
>   15

Logged

> 3 hours ago (01/09/18, 11:57am)

Level

> Warn

Logger

> Raven.Database.Indexing.ErrorLoggingConcurrentMergeScheduler

Comment: What Raven version?

Comment: raven version 3.5.4 build 35215